# Eliminar todas las apariciones de un caracter en codigo javascript

Tags: windows

Tengo un problema con el código que estoy trabajando, lo que pasa es que tiene barras que lo pusieron anteriormente por seguridad de la empresa.

Ahora estamos actualizando algunos detalles de la página pero eliminar uno a uno el

> "\"

Es un poco demorado, exista alguna herramienta que permita eliminar ese caracter del codigo?

```
!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a)
```

Manualmente sería algo así:

```
!function(a, b) {
    "object" == typeof module && "object" == typeof module.exports ? module.exports = a.document ? b(a, !0) : function(a) {
        if (!a.document)
            throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
        return b(a)
    }
```

¿Que comando/herramienta puedo utilizar para quitar `"/"`?

Comment: Usas algun sistema operativo en especifico?, quiza se podria solucionar con algun comando

Comment: Uso windows. :)

Comment: Veo, porque bien, si tuvieras linux, o la terminal de git para windows, podrias usar el comando sed, y con ello lo solucionarias

Comment: Quería ver el codigo compilado en la consola de google, pero esta lo estamos llamando desde: <html manifest="/media.appcache"> y no logro ver el codigo compilado.

Comment: Es posible que hablemos en el chat?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58027/discussion-between-jhosselin-gimenez-and-ivan-botero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basado en los comentarios, contamos en este caso con la herramienta `git`, independientemente de la version de Windows `git` contiene variantes de muchos de los comandos de GNU/Linux.

Para este caso, podemos entonces usar el comando `sed`, el cual se usa para buscar y reemplazar datos en un archivo.

#### Primero

Tienes que llegar al directorio donde se encuentra tu codigo:

```
cd c:\directorio\de\archivo\
```

#### Segundo

Procedemos a ejecutar el comando `sed`, asi:

```
sed -i 's/\\"/"/g' archivo.js
```

Lo que le estamos indicando al comando, lo podemos dividir en 3 partes:

1. `-i` este parametro indica que el cambio a realizar se debe guardar en el mismo archivo.
2. `'s/\\"/"/g'` este es el patron de busqueda/reemplazo, es decir, busca todos las apariciones de `\` y reemplazalas por `"`.
3. `archivo.js` este es el archivo sobre el que se realizara el cambio.

Mas informacion respecto al uso de sed: [aqui](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed).